# Recoger descripción de un campo file

Tags: php, twig, drupal

Buenas , tengo un problema en `Drupal 8` , es que cuando recojo desde el `template` el `field` de los archivos se como recoger su ruta pero no la descripción del archivo :

```
<a href="{{ file_url(node.field_file.entity.fileuri) }}" >{{node.field_file.entity.value}}</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución :

```
{{node.field_files.description}}
```